# is there a way to add custom query to a magento select rendered by a collection?

Tags: magento, collections

I have a magento collection for which if i echo the getSelect() function, i get a query something like this:

```
   SELECT 
    `table1`.*,
    `table`.*,
    `table3.fieldy` AS 'fieldname'
  .....
  FROM ....
  WHERE....
```

and i would like to change this query into something like this:

```
   SELECT 
    `table1`.*,
    `table`.*,
    `table3.fieldy` AS 'fieldname',
     (SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action == 2 and state == 0) then 1 else 0 end) as state from tbl1)   AS 'fieldname2'
    ......
    FROM....
    WHERE....
```

now, for where clause for instance, you can add text to the query by using

```
productCollection->getSelect()->where('query text');
```

but how could I add custom query text to the first part of the select?

Many thanks

Comment: It depends. What specifically would you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` function `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` to add Subselect to your query.
Or just add new subselect field to select as:

```
$this->getSelect()->columns(array($alias => $fullExpression));
```

Note: `$fullExpression` should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the note about brackets? Is this like with joinField where you can use {{table}} to refer to the table you are joining?

Comment: @Eric no, in this case we need to make sure that subselect is wrapped already. So it will result in following 
SELECT id, desc, (SUBSELECT) as alias FROM table